# Android Switch widget inside AlertDialog, not showing thumb image (on/off instead)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, uiswitch

I have a rather simple dialog with an `ArrayAdapter` inside. The adapter inflates the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/calendar_selection_switch"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="test test"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@id/calendar_selection_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="80dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I show this dialog, this is what I get:

[image: AlertDialog without the thumb image]

Notice the words "on" and "off" in tiny letters. No custom graphics or classes here, just out-of-the-box.

When I do this in an `Activity` I don't get that. Instead I get the normal thumb image, which is exactly what I want:

[image]

Even if I grow the size of the Switch it doesn't make any difference. It just makes the list's rows larger.

Here's the code to build and show the dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builderSingle.setTitle(R.string.cal_title);

builderSingle.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

final CalendarListAdapter cla = new CalendarListAdapter(this, calendarList, null);
builderSingle.setAdapter(cla, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        cla.toggleSelect(which);
    }
});
builderSingle.setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (saveCalendars(cla)) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
AlertDialog dialog = builderSingle.create();
dialog.show();
```

The `CalendarListAdapter` is a simple `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public class CalendarListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Calendar> {
```

There's no difference between the `Activity` version and the `AlertDialog` version for this class though.

I'm puzzled. What I do here is not very complicated. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/calendar_selection_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:switchMinWidth="48.0sp"
        android:thumb="@drawable/switch_selector"
        android:track="@drawable/switch_track"
        android:checked="false"/>
```

switch_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:visible="true"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/white"
                android:endColor="@color/white"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="14.0sp"/>
            <size
                android:width="28.0sp"
                android:height="28.0sp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="4.0sp"
                android:color="#11000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:visible="true"
            android:dither="true"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/white"
                android:endColor="@color/white"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="16.0sp"/>
            <size
                android:width="28.0sp"
                android:height="28.0sp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2.0sp"
                android:color="#11000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

switch_track.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:visible="true"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/white"
        android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2.0sp"
        android:color="#11000000"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="14.0sp"/>
    <size
        android:width="42.0sp"
        android:height="28.0sp" />
</shape>
```

Then in code you can do:

```
        aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    aSwitch.setTrackResource(R.drawable.switch_track_off);
                } else {
                    aSwitch.setTrackResource(R.drawable.switch_track);
                }
            }
        });
```

switch_track_off.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:visible="true"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00A4FD"
        android:endColor="#00A4FD"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2.0sp"
        android:color="#00A4FC"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="14.0sp"/>
    <size
        android:width="42.0sp"
        android:height="28.0sp" />
</shape>
```

You can change the **colors** and other **styles** as you wish.

As far as I know this is the only reliable way to make `Switch` look and feel same in all `Android` versions anywhere in the app.

Please leave a comment if there is any better suggestion.

Comment: Well, I don't think this is an answer to the question I was asking though. Which is, why does the Switch look different when it's inside an AlertDialog and when it's inside an Activity?

Comment: I might use this as a workaround if nothing else works.

Comment: @Emmanuel are you using the `support library` version of `AlertDialog`? I think it is due to corrupt `drawable` in the `library`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchCalls"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
         />
```